# Change date format laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, date, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

i have something problem in there i want to change date format. 
this my view :

```
  @foreach ($posts as $post)
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                      <?php echo $post->id?>
                      </td>
                      <td class="mailbox-star"><?php echo $post->nama?></td>
                      <td class="mailbox-name"><?php echo $post->tanggal?></td>
                      <td class="mailbox-subject"><?php echo $post->deskripsi?></td>
                      <td class="mailbox-date"><?php echo $post->mulai?> - <?php echo $post->durasi?></td>
                      <td class="mailbox-date"><?php echo $post->total?> Jam</td>
                      <td class="mailbox-date">
                      <a href="<?php echo url('user/detail/'.$post->nama)?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i></a>
                      <a href="<?php echo url('user/edit/'.$post->id)?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
                      <a href="<?php echo url('user/delete/'.$post->id) ?>" class="btn btn-xs btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
```

and my controller :

```
    public function getIndex()
    {   
        $posts = DB::table("lembur_karyawan")
        ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
        ->paginate(6);

        return view('user',['posts'=>$posts]);
    }
```

this my view and what i want to do:

[image]

if someone tell me to use carbon please explain how to use it ?

NB : i use laravel 5.1

Comment: you can use `date('Y-m-d')` of php.

Comment: `$post->tanggal` is supposed to contain date right? and you might be doing echo inside foreach.

Comment: yes. but i getting error if i use date format from php. would u explain how to use it ?

Comment: You cannot use php date because php date fetch the current date. However, what you need is only to convert the date you have in database. So it won't work

Comment: try Carbon, 
[link](http://carbon.nesbot.com)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php echo date('d F Y', strtotime($post->tanggal)); ?>
```

Where

- d - The day of the month (from 01 to 31)
- F - A full textual
  representation of a month (January through December)
- Y - A four digit
  representation of a year

Comment: @ivansetiadi, glad that it helped you :).

Answer (score 9):

```
//replace
<td class="mailbox-name"><?php echo $post->tanggal?></td>
//to 
<td class="mailbox-name"><?php echo date('d M Y',strtotime($post->tanggal)); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 6):

It is better to use php `Carbon` date format in the view file.

If `<?php echo $post->tanggal?>` is which gets the date then:

This will work:

`<?php echo Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $post->tanggal)->format('d M Y') ?>`

The above returns the same output as you want.

If you want to change the format further. Then this [link](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) might help.

Carbon is inherited from PHP DateTime class. So if you are using laravel i recommend you to use Carbon.

Answer (score 5):

If you could use Eloquent, you could automatically cast the column to a Carbon date object.

You'd need a `Post` model and would have to make sure you've included `tanggal` in the columns that are cast to dates.

```
class Post extends Model {

    protected $dates = ['tanggal'];
```

Then Laravel will automatically convert the date into a Carbon object, which gives you access to all sorts of handy functions.

Then within your view just output the date in the format you're after.

```
$post -> tanggal -> format('d m Y');
```

You can read more on the helpful methods Carbon gives you here: http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/

And you can find out what different letters within the argument passed to `format` do here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Comment: This should be the right answer. It is the right way to manipulate date in Laravel +1. Thanks @matt-mcdonald.

Answer (score 5):

this will 100 percent solve your issue

```
{{ date('jS F Y',strtotime($post->tanggal)) }}
```

Answer (score 4):

use this format

```
echo date('jS F Y',strtotime($post->tanggal));
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php